# How to Authenticate External Oauth Token in Azure using .Net core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, federated-identity

I have an application which is hosted in Azure, I am able to authenticate the Bearer token which are generated by the Client (appId) Id which are under our same Tenent,.

Now I would Like to authenticate some other external tenant token which is also hosted in Azure but different Tenenat..

I was trying to add through Federated Credential, but  I am getting Below error while generate the access Code.

Attached the mapping which I have done in Azure. I am  not sure I am going in the right direction.

[image]

Error is:

[image]

Any Help on this is much appreciated

```
"error_description": "AADSTS700222: AAD-issued tokens may not be used for federated identity flows.\r\nTrace ID: 0154d231-b7d4-436c-9a5d-117d80460d00\r\nCorrelation ID: 0b9bd57f-6e20-4af9-961e-3f402345e707\r\nTimestamp: 2023-08-08 07:28:59Z",
```

Comment: Double check the scope param, it seems that you have entered a guid but want an URL `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.  [Check the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#third-case-access-token-request-with-a-federated-credential)

Comment: @Max Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried with https://graph.microsoft.com/.default also but still getting the same Error.  

Could you please help me with what is the configuration we need to enable in Azure Under Federation Tab. 

I assume this configuration is to Enable Authentication for external applications using Auth Code where I can enable for any Azure, GCP, AWS hosted application.

Much appreciated your help on this.

AADSTS700222: AAD-issued tokens may not be used for federated identity flows.\r\nTrace ID: 86761c24-0783-40e3-a7c7-6bdf644f2000\r\nCorrelation ID:

Comment: I found this Video Helpful. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ0gCJYMUKI

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred as you are creating federation between two **Azure AD identities** from different tenants. I have one **access token** created from one tenant with below claims decoded in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms):

[image]

Now, I used above claim values in creating **federated credentials** in application of different tenant like below:

[image]

When I tried to generate access token with federated credentials via Postman, I too got **same error**:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com:443/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: appId
grant_type:client_credentials
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_assertion:<token_from_other_tenant>
client_assertion_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, creating federation between two **Azure AD identities** from the same or different tenants is **not supported**. To confirm that, you can check this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/workload-identities/workload-identity-federation-considerations#azure-active-directory-issuers-arent-supported).

Alternatively, I created one **access token** for external IDP (auth0) having below claims:

[image]

Now, I created new **federated credentials** in application with above claim values:

[image]

When I used above token as **`client_assertion`**, token generated successfully with **federated** credentials like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Azure Active Directory Workload Identity Federation with external OIDC IdP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ0gCJYMUKI)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have tried these steps and it is working now for both Azure Tenants and external Oauth Issuer. However, I have one small question, what is subject Identifier in this case. will it change for every user login. I tried it is changing for every user Login and I felt external application should use the common credential flow to Generate the Oauth token.